# How I will get to know that whether my child thread has completed execution or it has thrown an exception

Tags: multithreading

Suppose my main thread has started a few child threads and i have used join method so that main thread will execute after the child threads have finished its execution.
But now say child thread has thrown some exception, so in this case how would I know that child threads have thrown exception?

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO.  I think we'll need to know more in order to give you a good answer.  Can you please tell us what operating system you are using, and what programming language?  You can click "edit" and add this information to your question.

Comment: You'll always know, the program crashes with an unhandled exception.  The Task class is a bit special, but when you use Join() then you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following post can help

> Method 1: try ... catch in child thread
>
> Method 2: set the exception handler UncaughtExceptionHandler for the thread
>
> Method 3: catch the exception through the get method of Future

[Exception handling in Java child threads](http://www.fatalerrors.org/a/exception-handling-in-java-child-threads.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Overview**

Great question! There are a few ways to handle this implementation, each with their own benefits. Since the Java Concurrency Library is quite robust, I will be explaining the processes with Java Examples, but the concepts translate well to other languages.

**Proactive**

A proactive approach attempts to handle all exceptions within the child threads. Below is the `run()` method in a `thread` implementation.

```
public void run() {
    try {
        computations();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        // Handle the exeception
    }
}
```

This can be quite beneficial because threads can act more independently and allow themselves to die if they require it.

**Uncaught Exception Handler**

In this implementation, the ExceptionHandler's `uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable t)` is overridden and acts as the handler for the children `threads` in conjunciton with a [ThreadFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html). Here, we allow the `thread`'s implementation of `run()` to require no exception handling to work safely. The `exception`, if thrown will be caught by the `ThreadFactory`'s `ExceptionHandler` instead. This can be beneficial because it requires `exception` handling to be standard between many thread implementations as well as removes the handling from the thread design.

**Note** - Exceptions throw from `thread` only execute the exception handler when executed via `execute()`. `submit()` on the other hand will return any exception as a part of the `thread` status.

**Thread Pool Executor Handler**

In this implementation, one would override the `afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t)` method for handling the `Exceptions`. This acts similarly to the above example except this will be used in conjunction with a [ThreadPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html). However, there are a few differences to note; this method should be utilized when you require `thread`-specific actions to recover or kill the `thread.

**Future Get**

In this approach, the implementation will include the use of [Futures](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/Future.html).

```
Future<?> myFuture = threadPool.submit(new myThreadImpl());
try {
        myFuture .get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // Maintain status
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // ... Handle the exception
    }
```

With the use of `submit()`, `myFuture().get()` will re-throw any exception from the thread if one was thrown during execution by wrapping it in an `ExecutionException`. This can be beneficial because it allows for `exception` handling to occur when attempting to access the results from the `get()`.